# Aluminium or Aluminum?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed today that both the tags "Aluminium" and "Aluminum" are used on this site. It is somewhat debatable in my mind if a material even needs a tag, but regardless of that, which format should this site adopt?

Comment: Ah, the differences within the ligua franca! :) Are we going to get the same sort of issues with airplane & aeroplane, bonnet & hood of a car or trunk & boot of a car or the glove compartment versus the glove box, windshield & windscreen, safety belt & seat belt, sidewalk & pavement versus footpath, parking lot & car park, overpass & flyover, traffic circle & roundabout. Then there's the issue of ize endings versus ise endings. It's all part of the fun of English being an unregulated language. :) I'm not fussed whether the tag has Aluminium or Aluminum, we all know what they mean.

Comment: @Fred - Hopefully, no, we won't end up having lots of similar issues.  But if we do, it's trivial enough to create the synonyms and resolve the matter.

Comment: @GlenH7 I agree, from what I seen so far matters are quickly resolved here

Comment: Tag synonyms are indeed the solution here. Indeed, a decision only *must* be made when the word in question will be made into a tag. For general use in questions, answers, and comments, there's no need to choose a standard since most English speakers will understand either term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard on Stack Exchange is for tags to use US English, per [Shog9's answer on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873/254929). In this particular case the spelling can be [something of a sticky wicket](http://grammarist.com/spelling/aluminium-aluminum/) so the easiest course is to pass the buck upstairs and just follow the same standard as the rest of the network. I've made them synonyms to help a bit with usability.

Comment: Understandably, still the suffix -ium means metallic element,[link] see here (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ium).

Comment: Ah, yes. Like "Platinum" and "Molybdenum."

Comment: Or perhaps; Helium, Lithium, Beryllium, Sodium, Magnesium, Potassium, Calcium, Scandium, Titanium, Vanadium, Chromium, Gallium, Germanium, Selenium, Rubidium, Strontium, Yttrium, Zirconium, Niobium, Technetium, Ruthenium, Rhodium, Palladium, Cadmium, Indium, Tellurium, Cerium, Praseodymium, Neodymium, Promethium, Samarium, Europium, Gadolinium, Terbium, Dysprosium, Holmium, Erbium, Thulium, Ytterbium, Lutetium, Hafnium, Rhenium, Osmium, Iridium, Thallium, Polonium, Francium, Radium, Actinium, Thorium, Protactinium, Uranium, Neptunium, Plutonium, Americium, Curium, Berkelium, Californium...

Comment: Also there's: Einsteinium, Fermium, Mendelevium, Nobelium, Lawrencium, Rutherfordium, Dubnium, Seaborgium, Bohrium, Hassium, Meitnerium, Darmstadtium, Roentgenium, Copernicium, Flerovium, Livermorium, and literally every systematically named element.

Comment: All that Versus; Platinum, Molybdenum and Tantalum

Comment: The place for you to make this argument is in an answer.

Comment: It's just a joke :)

Comment: It is worth noting that the "US English" directive is for tag names only.  Feel free to write about alumin**i**um in your questions and answers as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another (admittedly very weak, but still a reality) reason to stick with US English: we Americans tend to be keenly oblivious of the existence of the rest of the world, and I would say it's a rare American indeed who is even aware of the "aluminum/aluminium" dichotomy.

On the other hand I think most non-Americans are aware that Americans say it differently than everyone else (am I wrong?). Therefore, going with "aluminum" as the default (and "aluminium" as a synonym) will result in the least amount of confusion (and a lot of dead puppies).

Comment: As an American, I'm a little ashamed to admit this is quite accurate.

Comment: @Ethan48 Then you aren't *quite* as American as you suppose!

Comment: Users who select the synonym tag while writing their question will see the question automatically updated to the target tag.  So those who prefer the non-US spelling can select it all they want; the site will fix things automagically.